# JSCodeShift: Creating a Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

I am currently using JSCodeShift in order to migrate from amplify to jquery ajax service calls accross my application. I am trying to create a return statement in my JSCodeShift transform file but keeping coming across a redundant error which I am unable to figure out because of less documentation. Has anyone created a return statement or in JSCodeShift terms "returnExpression".

This is what I want to add into the function block body:

```
return $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            url: config.urls.updateContractExemptionUrl.replace(/\{accountNumber\}/, accountNumber)
        });
```

This is the error I keep coming across:

```
 ERR services/dataservice.contracts.js Transformation error
Error: no value or default function given for field "argument" of ReturnStatement("argument": Expression | null)
    at add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jscodeshift/node_modules/recast/node_modules/ast-types/lib/types.js:576:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jscodeshift/node_modules/recast/node_modules/ast-types/lib/types.js:593:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.value [as returnStatement] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jscodeshift/node_modules/recast/node_modules/ast-types/lib/types.js:592:34)
    at /home/dev/InventoryProjectGitNew/cbs-inventory-web/cbs-inventory-web-client/app/scripts/transform.js:29:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at NodePath.<anonymous> (/home/dev/InventoryProjectGitNew/cbs-inventory-web/cbs-inventory-web-client/app/scripts/transform.js:26:26)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jscodeshift/dist/Collection.js:76:36
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Collection.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jscodeshift/dist/Collection.js:75:18)
```

This is the my transforms file that I have written till now:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
module.exports = function (fileInfo, api, options) {

    var j = api.jscodeshift,
        root = j(fileInfo.source),
        requestsInformation = [];

    function RequestDetails() {
        var self = this;
        self.name = '';
        self.dataType = '';
        self.url = '';
        self.parameters = [];
    }

    function hasJQueryDependencyImported() {
        var checkJQueryLiteral = root.find(j.Literal, { value: 'jquery' }),
            checkJQueryParameter = root.find(j.Identifier, { name: '$' });
        return checkJQueryLiteral.length !== 0 && checkJQueryParameter.length !== 0;
    }

    function createAjaxRequest(requestInfo, returnExpression) {
        var functionBlocks = root.find(j.FunctionDeclaration);
        functionBlocks.forEach(function (block) {
            var functionBody = block.value.body.body;
            functionBody.forEach(function (statement, index) {
                if (statement.type === 'ReturnStatement' && statement.argument.type === 'CallExpression' && !!statement.argument.callee.object && statement.argument.callee.object.name === 'amplify') {
                    functionBody.splice(index, 1);
                    functionBody.push(j.returnStatement());
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function collectRequestInfo(requestDefinition) {
        var currentRequest = j(requestDefinition),
            requestInfo = new RequestDetails(),
            url = currentRequest.find(j.ObjectExpression).get(0).parentPath.value.properties[1],
            returnExpressions = root.find(j.ReturnStatement,
                {
                    argument: {
                        type: 'CallExpression',
                        callee: {
                            type: 'MemberExpression',
                            object: {
                                type: 'Identifier',
                                name: 'amplify'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        requestInfo.name = currentRequest.find(j.Literal).get(0).parentPath.value.value;
        requestInfo.dataType = currentRequest.find(j.ObjectExpression).get(0).parentPath.value.properties[0].value.value;
        requestInfo.url = url.value.object.object.name + '.' + url.value.object.property.name + '.' + url.value.property.name;
        returnExpressions.forEach(function (amplifyRequest) {
            var requestDetails = amplifyRequest,
                properties;
            if (requestDetails.value.argument.arguments[0].value === requestInfo.name) {
                properties = requestDetails.value.argument.arguments[1].properties;

                properties.forEach(function (property) {
                    requestInfo.parameters.push(property.value.name);
                });
            }
        });

        createAjaxRequest(requestInfo, returnExpressions);
        requestsInformation.push(requestInfo);
    }

    var amplifyLiteral = root.find(j.Literal, { value: 'amplify' });
    amplifyLiteral.remove();

    var amplifyRequestDeferredLiteral = root.find(j.Literal, { value: 'amplify.request.deferred' });
    amplifyRequestDeferredLiteral.remove();

    var amplifyParameters = root.find(j.Identifier, { name: 'amplify' });
    amplifyParameters.forEach(function (path) {
        if (path.parentPath.parentPath.value.type === 'FunctionExpression' && path.parentPath.parentPath.value.id === null) {
            j(path).remove();
        }
    });

    var allAmplifyRequestDefinitions = root.find(
        j.ExpressionStatement,
        {
            expression: {
                type: 'CallExpression',
                callee: {
                    type: 'MemberExpression',
                    object: {
                        type: 'MemberExpression',
                        object: {
                            type: 'Identifier',
                            name: 'amplify'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );

    if (allAmplifyRequestDefinitions.length) {
        allAmplifyRequestDefinitions.forEach(function (ampReqDef) {
            collectRequestInfo(ampReqDef);
        });

        // Do this after collecting information about the requests to be built
        allAmplifyRequestDefinitions.remove();
    }

    if (!hasJQueryDependencyImported()) {
        var defineBlock = root.find(j.CallExpression, {
            callee: {
                type: 'Identifier',
                name: 'define'
            }
        });

        defineBlock.forEach(function (expression) {
            var dependencies = expression.value.arguments[0].elements,
                depdendenciesArguments = expression.value.arguments[1].params,
                jqueryDependency = j.literal('jquery'),
                jqueryArgument = j.identifier('$');

            // Should be at index of last argument + 1
            dependencies[depdendenciesArguments.length + 1] = jqueryDependency;
            depdendenciesArguments[depdendenciesArguments.length + 1] = jqueryArgument;
        });
    }

    return root.toSource({quote: 'single'});
};
```

Check the function **createAjaxRequest** where I am trying to create a Ajax request using jscodeshift.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Do you want to create an empty return statement? I.e. `return;` ? The error seems pretty self explanatory to me. Which part do you not understand? FWIW, there is no such thing as a "return expression". `return` is a statement (which is why the functions are called `[r|R]eturnStatement`.

Comment: No @FelixKling I do not want to create an empty return statement. I want to create an ajax request mentioned above. I did try to push j.returnStatement() with parameters like arguments but I may have not been passing correct arguments

Comment: An example of the input would be useful. What you are doing seems to be more complex than it should be, or even wrong.  *" I may have not been passing correct arguments"* If you want to create something like `return $.ajax();`, then the argument to `returnStatement` needs to be a `CallExpression`: `j.returnStatement(j.callExpression(j.memberExpression(j.identifier('$'), j.identifier('ajax'))))` or a bit simpler: `j.returnStatement(j.template.expression\`$.ajax()\`)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you so much for your response. It does help here. I wanted some of your feedback on your comment 'seems to be more complex than it should be or even wrong'. I understand and even feel the same. But I didnt find an alternative to do it in other way as all the ajax request information had to be collected and then ajax requests had to be created. A check had to be made whether or not jquery is imported. If it is not imported, add them as a dependency. Your feedback would be helpful. Would you mind providing few pointers if I share you sample code and the transform file?

Comment: Best would be to create a http://astexplorer.net/ example (go to "Transform" and select "jscodeshift"). Sure, maybe all the things you are doing are necessary, impossible to tell without knowing anything about the input ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Hi Felix... I have added my input and the transform file in the following AST example. http://astexplorer.net/#/71OoxeNCle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127252/discussion-between-ankit-tanna-and-felix-kling).